# How to change log levle in WSO2 API Manager 3.1.0 in Container Environment?

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

Is there a way to dynamically change the log levels in the API manager in a containerized environment, where the user cannot log in and change the values in log4j2.properties? I am aware that log4j2.properties gets hot deployed when we make changes, but how to do the same in a docker/K8s scenario.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple options to enable logs in the running servers. But in a server running in a container you can take the following actions,

1. Access required containers/pods and do the changes to log4j2.properties
2. Respawn a new cluster by modifying log4j2.properties
3. Configure logs of each node by accessing the management console(3.1.0 WUM only)[1]
4. Configure logs per APIs in each pod by using REST API(3.1.0 WUM only)[2]

[1] https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/3.1.0/administer/logging-and-monitoring/logging/setting-up-logging/#enable-logs-for-a-component-via-the-ui
[2] https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/3.1.0/administer/logging-and-monitoring/logging/setting-up-logging-per-api/